# Why is the Blue Neighbourhood trilogy called so?

Tags: music-video, album-title

As clear from the title, why is Troy Sivan's music video trilogy and album [*Blue Neighbourhood*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blue_Neighbourhood) called so?

Is it a reference to man's world? As blue represent men - or is there some other meaning?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Troye explains](http://superfame.com/post/troye-sivan-blue-neighbourhood-album/):

> “I mean, it was a lyric from Wild. Leave this Blue Neighbourhood.”
>
> “Basically, I come from Perth, which is a moderately sized city of 2
>   million people. From within that, I come from a really small Jewish
>   community. I feel like I have had this really sheltered, perfect
>   suburban upbringing.”
>
> “And so, all of these stories that I have written come from that
>   place. And take place in that context of this Blue Neighbourhood. It’s
>   not necessarily a bad thing.”
>
> “It’s the mundaneness of it, but it’s where your truth is. That’s
>   where it all happened for me, so it only felt natural to call the
>   music video trilogy and the album that.”